# How to setup NFT on a marketplace for another person

Tags: ether, wallets, myetherwallet, nft

I have been tasked to set up selling NFT on marketplaces like Opensea etc. The issue is how do I perform all these tasks without getting access to their wallet credentials or private key.

The only option I see is to access their computer screen and upload NFTs on marketplaces.

Thanks